# I can't mark multiple strings in my statement if, i want to make talking console app and when is typed / chat is over

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging, visual-build-professional

```
using System;

namespace Let_sTalk
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {         
            Console.Write("<-:");
            string q = Console.ReadLine();
            string w = Console.ReadLine();
            string e = Console.ReadLine();

            if (q, w, e == "/")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("over");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is invalid C# syntax. You cannot combine multiple evaluations into a single equality operator like this. You need to explicitly write out each operation. I suggest reading through C# tutorials and language guides.

Comment: Your title is nearly incomprehensible ("marking" strings???). the body of the post offers no clarification or explanation nor does it ask a question.  Four of the five tags selected do not apply.  Please visit the [help] ats soon as you can and study [ask]

Comment: My english is low, becose i used google translate maybe translated badly

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the comma (`,`) symbol to separate variables in an if statement. That's invalid C# syntax.

Also, in C# string comparison is done with the `Equals` function. The `==` will still work in most cases, but there are some additional error handlings with the `Equals` function.

If you want to check if ***at least*** one of the `q, w, e` variables is equal to `/`, then use the following code:

```
if (q.Equals("/") || w.Equals("/") || e.Equals("/"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("over");
}
```

If you wish to check if ***all*** `q, w, e` variables are equal to `/`, then you have to replace the `||` (**or** operator) with `&&` (**and** operator) like so:

```
if (q.Equals("/") && w.Equals("/") && e.Equals("/"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("over");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation